# What's the likelihood of CarPlay support in RN?

Tags: react-native, expo, carplay

We're building a mobile app that we need CarPlay and Android Auto support for. I noticed that there's very little in the way of documentation/discussion around CarPlay + RN, but it seems that RN straight up doesn't support CarPlay.

Is this not something that's on the roadmap at all? What might be the steps to add CarPlay AA support in RN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CarPlay support isn't on the roadmap for React Native to my knowledge. You could try forking React Native and getting it to compile for CarPlay, though.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [react-native-carplay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-carplay)